# How do I lookup a value in another zoo object?

Tags: r, join, dplyr, time-series, zoo

I am trying to find a way to lookup a value in another zoo object. Suppose I have the following timeseries:

```
a <- read.zoo(data.frame(date=as.Date('2011-12-31') + 0:8, reldt=c(rep(as.Date("2012-02-01"),3), rep(as.Date("2012-03-01"),3), rep(as.Date("2012-01-01"),3)), col2=seq(11,19)), FUN = as.Date)
a
           reldt      col2
2011-12-31 2012-02-01 11  
2012-01-01 2012-02-01 12  
2012-01-02 2012-02-01 13  
2012-01-03 2012-03-01 14  
2012-01-04 2012-03-01 15  
2012-01-05 2012-03-01 16  
2012-01-06 2012-01-01 17  
2012-01-07 2012-01-01 18  
2012-01-08 2012-01-01 19  

mon <- read.zoo(data.frame(date=c(as.Date('2012-01-01'), as.Date('2012-02-01'), as.Date('2012-03-01')), mc=letters[1:3], mc2=c(100,200,300)LETTERS[1:3]), FUN = as.Date)
mon
           mc mc2
2012-01-01 a  100
2012-02-01 b  200
2012-03-01 c  300
```

For every `reldt` in `a` I would like to lookup the value in the column `mon.mc2`. In other words, I would like to append the corresponding values in column `mon.mc2` to `a` so I would have a column `a.mc2` that is matched by `a.reldt=index(mon)`

Here is what I tried (as I know this works for data.frame but doesn't seem to work for zoo objects). **IT DOESN'T ALIGN CORRECTLY FOR SOME REASON** (I suspect zoo objects don't respect the order of the indexes as returned by `match(...)`):

```
a$mc2 <- as.numeric(coredata(mon[match(as.Date(coredata(a$reldt)), as.Date(index(mon)))]$mc2))
```

Here is the zoo object I would like to output:

```
          reldt      col2 mc2
2011-12-31 2012-02-01 11   200
2012-01-01 2012-02-01 12   200
2012-01-02 2012-02-01 13   200
2012-01-03 2012-03-01 14   300
2012-01-04 2012-03-01 15   300
2012-01-05 2012-03-01 16   300
2012-01-06 2012-01-01 17   100
2012-01-07 2012-01-01 18   100
2012-01-08 2012-01-01 19   100
```

> NOTE: I would prefer a base R solution using zoo but it would be
>   interesting to see other packages that might be useful

Comment: zoo objects must be all of the same type and if you try to mix types, as in the question, it will use the lowest common denominator so both of your zoo objects are character objects.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: I’m ok with that. This is just an example. Any idea on how to do the match properly here without downgrading to a data.frame? I’m really just looking how to do the match properly....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments both `a` and `mon` are character zoo objects which is unusual; however, we can still do it by matching `a$reldt` to `as.character(time(mon))`. From that create a new zoo object `mc2` and merge that with `a`.

```
 mc2 <- zoo( coredata(mon$mc2)[match(a$reldt, as.character(time(mon)))], time(a) )
 cbind(a, mc2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to first work with the dataframes and join them and then to transform into a zoo object (if you really want that).
The join can easily be done with the `dplyr` package. In the following code, `a2` and `mon2` are the data.frame versions of `a` and `mon`.

```
a2 <- data.frame(date=as.Date('2011-12-31') + 0:8, reldt=c(rep(as.Date("2012-02-01"),3), rep(as.Date("2012-03-01"),3), rep(as.Date("2012-01-01"),3)), col2=seq(11,19))

mon2 <- data.frame(date = c(as.Date('2012-01-01'), as.Date('2012-02-01'), as.Date('2012-03-01')), mc=letters[1:3], 
                  mc2=c(100,200,300))

library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
left_join(a2, mon2 %>% select(-mc), by = c("reldt" = "date")) %>%
  read.zoo(FUN = as.Date)

           reldt      col2 mc2
2011-12-31 2012-02-01 11   200
2012-01-01 2012-02-01 12   200
2012-01-02 2012-02-01 13   200
2012-01-03 2012-03-01 14   300
2012-01-04 2012-03-01 15   300
2012-01-05 2012-03-01 16   300
2012-01-06 2012-01-01 17   100
2012-01-07 2012-01-01 18   100
2012-01-08 2012-01-01 19   100
```

Comment: Yup, and my solution in the question would work if I downgrade to a data.frame. I guess it is a way but wondering if I can just keep it as a zoo object

Comment: You can also join two zoo objects by their index. However in your case you don't want to join index and column which is very uncommon for timeseries objects.

Comment: You can check merge.xts from the xts package